# Accessing a Resource Calendar with no mailbox via EWS and C#

Tags: c#, resources, calendar, shared, exchangewebservices

Our Exchange Admins (Exchange 2010 SP1) have setup a shared resource calendar.  **There is no mailbox assigned to this resource calendar**.  I want to be able to read the meetings using EWS and C#.

Snippet:

```
        ExchangeService esvc = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
        esvc.Credentials = new WebCredentials(username, password, "ourplace.org");
        esvc.Url = new Uri("https://OWA.OURPLACE.ORG/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

        FolderId shareFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, "Shared Calendar Name");
        CalendarFolder.Bind(esvc, shareFolderId);
```

the bind statement throws the error: "The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it."

How can I read the items on a Share Resource Calendar that has no associated mailbox... or is it even possible?

Thanks !!

Comment: Hi @user2308563, did you find an answer?  Tried answer below withou success. <br>
When right click My Calendar > myown@company.com > Properties </br>
under places it reads: \\myown@company.com <br>
On the other one it reads \\Jhon_Doe

Answer (score 2):

Bind to that Calendar with a mail-Adress

Create first of all a FolderId:

```
FolderId parkplatzCalendarId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar,"de.calendar.name@company.com");
```

Then bind to this one:

```
CalendarFolder calendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(_service, parkplatzCalendarId);
```

Now you can use this calendar!

```
CalendarView cView = new CalendarView(start, end, int.MaxValue);

cView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Subject, AppointmentSchema.Start, AppointmentSchema.End, AppointmentSchema.Duration, AppointmentSchema.LastModifiedName, AppointmentSchema.Organizer, AppointmentSchema.Categories);

FindItemsResults<Appointment> appointments = calendar.FindAppointments(cView);
```

With something like that ;D

Comment: It's also important to note that the user you're logged in as needs delegate access to that resource calendar.  I just had a two hour run in with that permissions issue.

Comment: Worked as said, connected with a user that had delegate access, then created folderId object with an e-mail format of the calendar: delegaceCal@company.com

Answer (score 0):

If the calendar is actually not in any particular mailbox, then it should be in a public folder, and you should look in a subfolder `WellKnownFolderName.PublicFoldersRoot`.

Otherwise, please tell where exactly does it appear in Outlook folders hierarchy.